# VBA subtracting address

Tags: vba, excel

I was just wondering will it be possible to subtract something from an address? I mean like data.Address -1?

I have here a code that would return the address of a cell based on a keyword. what I wanted to do is after finding the keyword (and its address), I would like to subtract 1 from it so that the keyword I am trying to find wont be deleted.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Target")

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

wordSearch = "data"

Set aCell = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=wordSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlDown, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Sheets("Target").Range("A1:" & aCell.Address).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to delete the content of all rows that sit above `aCell`, try replacing

```
Sheets("Target").Range("A1:" & aCell.Address).Select
```

with

```
Sheets("Target").Range("A1:" & aCell.offset(-1,0).Address).ClearContents
```

You do not have to select the range so your next two lines can be removed.

In case you are actually trying to delete the rows above `aCell` and also shift the remaining rows up (instead of just deleting), try

```
Sheets("Target").Range("A1:" & aCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address).Delete shift:=xlUp
```

instead of the `.ClearContents` method.

Comment: ClearContents won't shift them up, which is what Erin does in the original code.

Comment: @DougGlancy - Thank you for pointing out: I amended the original answer accordingly.